# How can I get the leftover room space?

Tags: arrays, c++11, for-loop, while-loop

So this is the task I need help with:

The blueprint of a house is made on a unit square grid sheet. All rooms must be rectangular. So far, N rooms have been drawn on the blueprint. Each room is defined by the upper left and lower right corners. One field of the square grid is given by the x and y coordinates, the coordinates of the upper left field (0,0). The x-coordinates increase horizontally and the y-coordinates increase vertically. The designer wants to calculate how many new rectangular rooms can be added if the two sides of any two new rooms cannot have a common part, and all four sides are adjacent or existing, or the side of the house. The rooms planned so far are such that every free space is rectangular. Make a program that tells you what the largest possible new room area can be in your plan.

Input:

The first line of the standard input has the number of rooms in the design (1≤N≤10,000) and the coordinates of the upper left (FX, FY) and lower right (AX, AY) corners of the house (0 ≤ FX < AX ≤ 1000, 0 ≤ FY < AY ≤ 1000), separated by a space. Each of the following N lines has coordinates (FX ≤ LFXi ≤ RAXi ≤ AX, FY ≤ LFYi ≤ RAYi ≤ AY) of the upper left (LFXi, LFYi) and lower right (RAXi, RAYi) of each room, separated by a space.

Output:

The first line of the standard output should be the area of ​​the largest new room!

Theres an example in the link and its the basic input and output that you can test the program with.
I translated this task from hungarian so the Példa=example , Bemenet=input , Kimenet=output. I would be really happy to get some help with this taks because for me it is a little bit too hard.

[Basic input example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3v2O.jpg)

Comment: Do you have an actual question that we can help with?  Are you looking for help understanding the question, analysing possible ways to approach the problem or something to do writing the program?

Comment: Well I need some help to do and approach this programing task because my teacher does not helps a lot and did not even showed us the tools and codes to start and do this task so this  exceeds my skills  :/

Comment: Ok, what parts of C++ syntax are you allowed to use?  Most professors use really antiquated C++ syntax (from the 80s and 90s) instead of using modern C++ style. 
 So often they have requirements that you have to use certain kinds of syntax. 
 Can you use idiomatic C++ (like a vector)?  Can you use a struct?  Can you use C++ style IO?  Or does it not matter?